# I cant login to Gmail with Selenium anymore

Tags: selenium

I freshly installed Selenium and ran it with some python code, using Chrome browser (Chromium), on Ubuntu.

Chromium 79.0.3945.79 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04

As you can see I cannot login to gmail, this is what I get when I enter the correct email and password.

EDIT: I tried it on GeckoDriver (Firefox 71.0) as well and encountered the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Is your Firefox up to date?

Comment: @dmb OP is using Chromium. Why you asking about Firefox?

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, I got them mix they kinda look alike in Ubuntu. But still, is your chromium up to date? It looks more of a browser type or error rather than Selenium. If you freshly installed Ubuntu then it's highly possible Chromium isn't the latest.

Comment: @dmb
I guess its up to date. I've edited my post to include chromium version.

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. Public sites can sense the automation (webdriver/*driver) of the client browser and restrict access based on that. Automation, if exploited, could compromize user accounts. Same, an automated browser could pull attacks on that site.
Therefore, only development accounts/variants of the public site should allow logins through an automated browser.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted, as this is very true and was reported on several websites past week. Also Google says so: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428 as linked from an error page one might see when trying to log in manually with the same browser (the very "Learn more" link in the screenshot in the question).

Answer (score -1):

Selenium with Java

Finally I did it but its little tricky and achieve the following scenario
-> Login with gmail (Google Chrome Version 83)
-> Compose an email
-> select different label
-> send it to myself
-> and verified the mail received

Please let me know if help is need to complete the task

No need to create new account, just use your existing one ....

Thank you